# How to launch and debug spring application on linux server?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, centos

I have a spring application on my local PC. And a VPS, run centos OS and has installed tomcat. My application could run well in localhost, but after I put it on the server(/tomcat/webapps) through ftp. It doesn't work any more and the tomcat will stop service when start that application. So what's the right steps to run application on tomcat on a linux server, and how can I check what's wrong with the application(like the debug log on local Eclipse)? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check Tomcat's server logs, (located in <~tomcat-installation-directory>/logs? You may find the possible cause for your server's crash. If you server and application is up and running, then you may do remote debugging using Eclipse.